# How can i capture Browser console log using selenium and java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to capture log for any js event trigger or error Using selenium and java.Any type of help or suggestion will be appreciated? I tried this code but it's not working properly

```
public void HomePageConsole () throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.id("drop-down")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-top-currency']/li[4]/a")).click();
       LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
          // System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
           //System.out.println("Checking ExitUnit: 5th Line will be true ");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Exit Unit Open : "+entry.getMessage().contains("has been triggered!"));

}}
```

Comment: I already added code, This code word with Mozilla only but sometimes not get appropriate result also result shows by timestamp.I want all log togeather so that I can check Js event

Comment: "not working properly" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void analyzeLog() {

    LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
        System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
        //do something useful with the data
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it works in all the browsers? Such as FF, Chrome, IE etc.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more efficient way to print the LogEntry by it's own toString override:

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
    System.out.println(entry.toString());
}
```